# Remove or modify navigation drawer overlay shadow in Flutter

Tags: flutter, shadow

I created a `Scaffold` widget with `appBar` and `drawer`.

As I open the drawer, there is a shadow over the `Scaffold`'s `body` widget. I'd like to either remove the shadow, make it not so "strong" or change the shade slightly.

I checked the docs and I didn't find any way to achieve this through public API.

Is there any way to remove the drawer menu's "drop shadow" on the body?

The elevation option is something different, even if I set it to 0, the overlay shadow on top of the body is still present.

[This](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/3720) issue's description's screenshots might help clarify what I want.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want to get rid of the shadow over the Scaffold body then you have to change the Scaffold's `drawerScrimColor`'s value to `Colors.transparent`.

Comment: Awesome, it's been added in this PR: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/31025

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried setting the drawer's `elevation` to `elevation: 0.0`?

Comment: Yes, I mentioned it in the question: "The elevation option is something different, even if I set it to 0, the overlay shadow on top of the body is still present."

Answer (score 3):

check this

```
drawerTheme:
          DrawerThemeData(scrimColor: Colors.transparent, elevation: 0.5),
```